# How safe is elementary OS

Tags: security

This question sounds like exact duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/30032/how-safe-is-ubuntu.

May or may not, but I would like to know *How safe is elementary OS* ?

Comment: you mean that 'in general' and not specific to server software?

Comment: yes 'in general' @Adityaultra :)

Comment: a suitable site for general linux safety is http://thepcspy.com/read/linux-isnt-invulnerable/

Comment: @Adityaultra 'in general' --I mean specific to elementary OS, not general linux.

Answer (score 2):

This question isn't totally fully answerable. Security is complicated and it largely depends on you, the user. Unsafe behavior, specifically you willingly giving away admin privileges, is the biggest vulnerability in any system. That said, some general kind of security advice:

- **Use a password and lock your session**. If someone can walk up to your computer and start using it, you've been compromised.
- **Run your updates**. Security updates are issued regularly. Make sure your system is up to date.
- **Don't run Terminal commands from the internet that you don't understand**. Some people just think it's funny to leave destructive commands out there and some people actually have malicious intent. But it's why there's a warning when pasting things into Terminal. If you don't understand every part of the command or deeply trust the person giving it to you, don't run it.
- **Don't install software from PPAs or Deb packages**. Installing software from 3rd party sources literally gives someone else administrative power on your computer. Don't do it unless you deeply trust the organization you're getting the software from.

Comment: So how do you suggest installing software - simply from the repositories?

Comment: @Tim That is the only verified secure source by a paid security team. If you install from outside the repositories, you are personally taking up that security burden. It's probably safe to trust well known organizations like Google, but it may not be safe to trust individuals.

Answer (score -1):

Don't think the answer will be way different from the mentioned one, elementary OS is Ubuntu too, and the *elementary* community on Launchpad is on pulse with reported special security vulnerabilities :)

Anyway, there are some bugs that make using the OS bit unsecure. These are, like, one that keeps out changing the layout from English on the lockscreen. Be careful if you have a password in a different character set :)

My most disappointing experience was when I logged in to Geary with an iCloud mail account (2-step verification off), and the day I found the password stolen right out of the application! As a cryptography profane, I see the folks did that with a fake sertificate.

ps: And yep, I finally reset it with the second mail account.

Comment: I appreciate you for your answer and upvoted. But --"Don't think the answer will be way different from the mentioned one"--are you sure? I'm not.